# Why echo $0 displays default shell even after changing it?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Why `echo $0` displays `-bash` even after changing it?
I changed my shell to `zsh` but when I try `echo $0`, it still displays `-

What I did...
I checked the available shells using

`cat /etc/shells`

Which displayed 
/bin/bash
/bin/zsh
...

I used `chsh -s /bin/zsh` to change shell

Comment: In the (now deleted) Stackoverflow version of this question you were already given alot of comments which you have not seemed to take heed of. For example, you were told you need to logout and log back in for the changed shell to take effect. Did you do that? It should behave as you expect after that.

Comment: Yes, it works. But, I wanted to know what's going on under the hood to get a better understanding of the system. I could not find the reasoning behind it. I am sorry if it's silly, I am beginner.

Answer (score 2):

So far no answer nor comment explicitly stated what `chsh` really does.

You seem to think `chsh` changes the current shell. No. It only changes some record that tells the OS what shell is your login shell. The record counts when your login shell is about to be started. The current shell (or any other already started shell) stays unaffected: it does not morph into another shell, it does not get killed and replaced by another shell.

Solutions like "log out and log back in" work because after logging back in you are given access to the login shell you chose. Any command that checks what your login shell is and runs it (as opposed to running some fixed shell independent of your choice) may be a solution. `su` in [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560055/108618) is such command.

Answer (score 1):

As [kaylum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/180169/kaylum) pointed out, you are still in the same user environment.

To refresh it you should log out & log in again or, if you prefer, use `su` command to re-login without losing your current session:

```
su - $USER
```

Your `echo $0` will work properly then.

after you exit this session with `exit` you'll be again in the former one.